# Change system tray icons

Tags: unity, icons, system-tray

My laptop's system tray currently looks like this:

[image]

The icons of Mega and Telegram don't follow the style of the others – they aren't white.

Where are these icons stored so I can change them?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Looked promising at first but after changing the files `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/{16x16,32x32,48x48,64x64,128x128,256x256}/apps/mega.png` and restarting Mega, it still has the same system tray icon. Its icon in the dash changed, though. I wasn't able to find the correct location, apparently. And especially not for Telegram as there is no package for it, as far as I'm aware of, as Telegram isn't installed via a Debian package.

Comment: Imho this is a dupe, and the answer should be updated if necessary

Comment: @Zanna I definitely agree that with the approach I intended to take, it's a duplicate. But there doesn't seem to be a file for this logo. I actually checked Mega's binary for this. There is an array containing strings like `:/images/tray_upload_ico.png`, `:/images/tray_download_ico.png`, `:/images/mega_logo.png`, etc. But there aren't such files (i.e. e.g. `mega_logo.png`) on my disk. Finding that icon file would be interesting but `dpkg-query -L megasync` doesn't seem to yield any icon files or alike. (At least, this explains why modifying the PNG images whose paths it printed didn't work.)

Comment: @Zanna What I intended to say: The approach in that other question doesn't appear to work, here.

Comment: Hmm... how can there be a logo with no file? Very strange... but retracting my vote, in uncertainty

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways

1. Use an icon set with monochrome images for your apps
2. Use your own custom icons to the icon set

You can create icons for Mega and Telegram and add it to the custom icon pack.

Also, try using Papirus Icon theme. They have a monochrome icon set for task bar. Maybe, Mega and Papirus has icons in it.

[image]

https://github.com/PapirusDevelopmentTeam/papirus-icon-theme

PS : You can also use any icon themes with monochrome icons for app of your choice

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It changed all the icons, except the ones of Mega and Telegram: http://i.imgur.com/GrGuAO2.png

Comment: As you can see, the sample I fetched from the Github page includes Mega and Telegram. Do you see the above image in their Github page ? Check that area of description

Comment: Read this : https://github.com/bil-elmoussaoui/Hardcode-Tray

Comment: Icons are already there. At this location : /usr/share/icons/Papirus/22x22/panel  . If you are not able to get it, something wrong with the way you installed icon theme

Comment: I think it's because I didn't know I was supposed to run `hardcode-tray --conversion-tool Inkscape`. I assumed you yourself took the screenshot after installing and activating it on your system. I like the stock icons and would merely like to exchange the icons of Mega and Telegram, not the others. Whether they are from some icon pack or I made them myself, I don't really care. I already made the one for Mega anyways. But I would like to keep the others as they are.